# Authenticate user using ADFS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, azure, asp.net-web-api, adfs

We are developing ASP.Net MVC REST API and we want the user authentication should happen via ADFS for consuming the REST API. I read many blogs but didn't found any useful, wherein user could generate the Access Token by passing his credentials (username, password). The generated Token then would be sent to the REST API as a bearer token. The reason why we want the user to send his credential is because, we want to validate if the request is coming from trusted user and not from any random person. Also, we want to track which user has consumed what APIs etc.

The above requirement can be met with Azure AD, but I didn't found any way to do the same using ADFS. Any help would be appreciated. Also, are there any sample code we can get for the same?

Answer (score 0):

If your org or your customer already has AAD and federated with ADFS, it is fine to use Azure AD and the auth is still handled by ADFS.

If you don't have Azure AD, see ADFS 2016 TP4 and guidance at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593305.aspx that uses OPenIDConnect. It uses the Azure AD sample and modifies to consume ADFS. ADFS 2016 adds full support for OpenIDConnect & OAuth.

Thanks
//Sam (@MrADFS)